# Sending data between 2 Android devices

Tags: android, android-intent, sms-gateway, smslib

I have an App which records gps location details of the User. Now when the user clicks "Send" the data needs to be sent to the Another Android phone(Second user) and received by this same app installed in that phone. One way that I feel it can be done is through Sending an SMS and receiving and parsing the SMS to get the data. But SMS will cost the user, especially if he doesn't have an SMS offer pack activated.

Is there any other way of sending data. Can we use third part free SMS services like Way2SMS from our android code. Which is most preferred way(least burden of cost on the user).

Answer (score 1):

[Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) can probably solve your problems if your message is no larger than 4kb.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly an architecture decision that you have to make. As you mentioned sending data through SMS is one way of doing it, in this case you can try using third party APIs like [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/sms), in this case you'll have to cover the cost for sending the SMS (which is fair, the user doesn't have to pay directly for this).

You can also send these data to your backend server and then push back these data into the 2nd device  using [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) for example.

Also from a security stand point, it would be nice to send these data encrypted as your users trust you when sharing their locations with your app.